# Wise Installer, dialog on uninstall?

Tags: uninstallation, wise

With wise installer, how can I make the 'Remove' action display a dialog? I would like to have some options displayed to the user.

The modify seems to do this, but my remove action just causes the uninstall with no options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you but have you consider making another app (using wise scripts) that would act as a 'proxy' to uninstaller, so you execute it instead of uninstaller.

Within this application you can display any dialog you want and if needed execute "unwise32.exe /A install.log" to continue with removing.